# shell script: print paramaters from a for loop with $i

Tags: shell, scripting

I have a script called `hello.sh` and I invoke it like this:

```
./hello.sh yes no sure why how
```

I want to print all the parameters after the first two parameters: `sure why how`

Code:

```
for ((i = 3; i <= $#; i++));
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

But instead of `sure why how`, it prints `1 2 3`.

How do I print the parameter and not the index?

Comment: Can you capture the first two arguments if you need them (`arg1="$1"; arg2="$2"`) and then use `shift 2` to lose them, so arguments 3-N are in `"$@"`?

Comment: What scripting language is this?  It doesn't seem to be valid code.  Those double parenthesis look very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're echoing `$i` rather than the argument at position `$i`. Try:

```
args=("$@")

for ((i = 3; i <= $#; i++)); do
  echo ${args[$i]}
done
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this simpler, easier approach without arrays:

```
arg1="$1" arg2="$2"  # save $1 and $2

shift 2

for i; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

The first line is not required if you won't actually use those values later on.

**UPDATE**

Or as [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) pointed out, if you're using `bash`, and you want to avoid modifying `$@` with `shift`, you could do like this:

```
arg1="$1" arg2="$2"  # save $1 and $2

for i in ${@:3}; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: Based on the use of a C-style for-loop, the OP is presumably using `bash`. In that case, one could use `for i in ${@:3}; do` to avoid modifying `$@` with `shift`.